# Pushing key value pairs to an object in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have seven checkboxes, when one is checked or unchecked I want to push the currently checked boxes into the `checkedCheckboxes` object. When I `console.log` the key/value pairs inside the `if` statement I get the correct output, however, when I `console.log()` `checkedCheckboxes` after the updated values have been assigned I get this (the object at the bottom of the log):

[image: console log]

So I think there must something wrong with this line: `checkedCheckboxes = {...key, ...colourCheckbox[key]};`.

If anybody could tell me what, it would be a huge help.

Full code:

```
  // store checkbox values in an object;
  const colourCheckbox = {
    whiteBox: $('#white'),
    blueBox: $('#blue'),
    blackBox: $('#black'),
    redBox: $('#red'),
    greenBox: $('#green'),
    colourlessBox: $('#colourless'),
    multicolouredBox: $('#multicoloured')
  };

  // initialise object to store which checkboxes are checked
  let checkedCheckboxes = {};

  // store checked boxes in 'checkedBoxes'
  $('.colour-checkbox').change(() => {
    checkedCheckboxes.length = 0;
    for (const key in colourCheckbox) {
      if ($(colourCheckbox[key]).is(':checked')) {
        checkedCheckboxes = {...key, ...colourCheckbox[key]};
        console.log(key, colourCheckbox[key])
      }
    }
    console.log(checkedCheckboxes)
  });
```

Comment: Why are you using the spread operator on the `...key` and  `...colorCheckbox[key]`?

Comment: @CTL To push the key/value pairs to ```checkedCheckboxes```.

Comment: `key` is a string, so when you do `...key` you are essentially splitting the string character by character and inserting them as individual key-value pairs into the object.

Comment: Please show data as text, not as a picture of text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use spread operator if you doing it like this. Try to change your code to this

```
// store checkbox values in an object;
      const colourCheckbox = {
        whiteBox: $('#white'),
        blueBox: $('#blue'),
        blackBox: $('#black'),
        redBox: $('#red'),
        greenBox: $('#green'),
        colourlessBox: $('#colourless'),
        multicolouredBox: $('#multicoloured')
      };

      // initialise object to store which checkboxes are checked
      let checkedCheckboxes = {};

      // store checked boxes in 'checkedBoxes'
      $('.colour-checkbox').change(() => {
        checkedCheckboxes.length = 0;
        for (const key in colourCheckbox) {
          if ($(colourCheckbox[key]).is(':checked')) {
            checkedCheckboxes[key] = colourCheckbox[key];
            console.log(key, colourCheckbox[key])
          }
        }
        console.log(checkedCheckboxes)
      });
```